# keypress bug in FF?

Tags: keypress

```
$('input').keypress(function(e){
        var k = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;                                     
        console.log(k);     
});
<input type="text" name=""  autocomplete="off"/>
```

In FF for '.' (point) and for 'delete' it is the same code 46. 
AND for 'right' (right arrow) and for ' it is the same code 39. 
just to be 'safe' Chrome and IE7 don't fire nothing for keys like arrows, delete, insert, backspace etc

Comment: Jan Wolter has right: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Comment: On my laptop, the period "." char is the same physical as the "del" (in number pad mode). I wonder whether there are some linkage between the 2. But you are right, they shouldn't be the same code no.

Comment: and the code for % and left arrow is again the same (37)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really a bug per-say, just one of the many browser differences.  If you look on your number-pad, they are the same key, their mapping points to that key.

Comment: this was my first guess for . and delete, but is it also a good explanation  for ' and right arrow ?

Comment: @silversky: Yes, same reason...it's just some of the ways browsers differ that makes development a PITA sometimes.

Comment: then i'm stuck, because kwyup also doesn't work weel with delete or arrows. If you watch carefully you will see that in FF keyup don't fire nothing at first strike but on the second one, it fires twice.

Comment: @silversky: Look here, it may save you a lot of guess-work: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html

Comment: thank you, now I understand. it's not a bug because there is no regulation. Every browser it has it's own rules. And some times it happens to coinside (to be the same)

Comment: @silversky: Yep...sorry the answer sucks, but it's one of the (luckily) relatively few things left that's still **VERY** different between browsers.